# Why does transmute reorder bytes when transmuting from a byte array to a tuple of bytes and byte arrays?

Tags: rust

```rust
fn main() {
    let buffer: [u8; 16] = [ 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f ];
    let (a, b, c, d, e): (u8, u8, u8, [u8; 4], [u8; 9]) = unsafe { core::mem::transmute(buffer) };
    println!("{a:#x}");
    println!("{b:#x}");
    println!("{c:#x}");
    println!("{d:#x?}");
    println!("{e:#x?}");
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab7a1a4876026f62eb579c8501033243)

Output:

```
0x4
0x5
0x6
[
    0x0,
    0x1,
    0x2,
    0x3,
]
[
    0x7,
    0x8,
    0x9,
    0xa,
    0xb,
    0xc,
    0xd,
    0xe,
    0xf,
]
```

Why don't `a`, `b`, and `c` get the values 0x00, 0x01, and 0x02 (respectively)? Why do those values instead go into `d`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK tuples are layed out in memory similarly to structs, but those don't necessarily have memory layout with fields being in the same order as in struct definition. You can try to use `repr(C)` attribute onto a custom struct to preserve this order

[The Rustonomicon: Alternative representations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html)

```
#[repr(C)]
struct DecodedBytes(u8, u8, u8, [u8; 4], [u8; 9]);

fn main() {

    let buffer: [u8; 16] = [ 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f ];
   
    let DecodedBytes(a, b, c, d, e)  = unsafe { core::mem::transmute(buffer) };
    println!("{a:#x}");
    println!("{b:#x}");
    println!("{c:#x}");
    println!("{d:#x?}");
    println!("{e:#x?}");
}
```

> 0x0
> 0x1
> 0x2
> [
> 0x3,
> 0x4,
> 0x5,
> 0x6,
> ]
> [
> 0x7,
> 0x8,
> 0x9,
> 0xa,
> 0xb,
> 0xc,
> 0xd,
> 0xe,
> 0xf,
> ]

Comment: And in this specific case, the reason is probably that Rust tries to align array (in this case - to 4 bytes), even if it isn't strictly required, since this is expected to give a little more performance in common cases.